# How to take all the database backup in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have written a SQL cursor to take back up:

```
   DECLARE @databaseName NVARCHAR(50), @backupFilePath NVARCHAR(50),@backupFileName 
   NVARCHAR(50),@dateOfFile NVARCHAR(20)
   SET @backupFilePath = 'D:\Backup'  

   SELECT @dateOfFile = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) + 
   REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),108),':','') --20170416165910
   DECLARE cursorForBackup CURSOR FOR (SELECT 'Permanent_Employee')

   OPEN cursorForBackup   

   FETCH NEXT FROM cursorForBackup INTO @databaseName   
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
   BEGIN   
   SET @backupFileName = @backupFilePath + @databaseName + '_' + @dateOfFile + '.BAK'  
   BACKUP DATABASE @databaseName TO DISK = @backupFileName   
   FETCH NEXT FROM cursorForBackup INTO @databaseName   
   END   

   CLOSE cursorForBackup   
   DEALLOCATE cursorForBackup
```

SQL Server is connected to dev environment with valid IP and password

Here, I have specified the backupFilePath.
Though the query is running successfully but no backup file is getting generated in the path.

Can anyone help me if I am missing something

Success message:

> Processed 6256 pages for database 'YumThailand_Dev', file 'YumThailand_Dev' on file 1.
>   Processed 2 pages for database 'YumThailand_Dev', file 'YumThailand_Dev_log' on file 1.
>   BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 6258 pages in 1.129 seconds (43.304 MB/sec).

If anyone knows a better solution please suggest.

Comment: Stop re-inventing the wheel - just use [Ola's backup solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/).

Comment: And if you intend to be successful in dynamically generating path names, you need to **see** the names you generate. [Using your code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9db32beda97bb6842d83be5ed193f512), the file name of your backup file is: `D:\BackupPermanent_Employee_20200420211920.BAK` - does that look correct?

Comment: Thanks for the update SMor but it's still not generating the back up file in **D:\Backup**

Comment: Ola's backup solution is really helpfull, will try in that way. But could not understand why my script is not generating the backup file. even I tried this `   BACKUP DATABASE YumThailand_Dev
TO DISK = 'D:\Backup\backup.bak'` but no luck.

Comment: And how would you know what is going on? Where is your error handling? Did you fix your code? Did you look in the root directory of D: if you are still using the old code? Are you looking at the drives where your server instance is running (and not your local disk drives)? You say it produces those messages - but where / how? You work for a huge international company - maybe now is a good time to ask for help from coworkers.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ola's backup solution was helpful